# FTP can't list a directory containing umlaut character

Tags: node.js, ftp

I am creating some sort of ftp proxy, so I need to be access ftp as a client, so I used the package `ftp`. And of course it works perfectly fine, except that it cant seem to find directories with umlaut character.

Actually its not just the problem of this package, various ftp clients seem to have this issue, I've tried ftp.exe, ftp (linux), and they return (`550-The system cannot find the file specified.`) some clients however manage to be able to list it, like the browsers ftp-client (they're going to be deprecated however), Filezilla, or Winscp have no problem.

`OPT UTF-8 ON` seems to be ignored `500 Command not understood.`. The server does list it in `FEAT`, googling has been of no use since they just retort to using a different client, but I am programming this in node.

I'm not sure if code is needed, since the problem is probably has nothing to do with the code itself.

---

For those who are interested:

```js
var c = new (require("ftp"));
  c.on('ready', function() {
    c.list("ä",function(err, list) {
      if (err) throw err;
/* Uncaught Error: The system cannot find the file specified.
    at makeError (C:\node_modules\ftp\lib\connection.js:1067:13) {
  code: 550
*/
    });
  });
  c.connect(connectsettings);
```

### WinSCP log:

```
. 2021-01-12 16:52:22.576 ä;D;0;2021-01-12T15:47:00.000Z;1;"" [0];"" [0];---------;0
. 2021-01-12 16:52:22.712 Session upkeep
. 2021-01-12 16:52:22.740 Session upkeep
. 2021-01-12 16:52:23.077 Session upkeep
. 2021-01-12 16:52:23.578 Session upkeep
. 2021-01-12 16:52:23.866 Changing directory to "ä".
> 2021-01-12 16:52:23.871 CWD ä
< 2021-01-12 16:52:24.061 250 CWD command successful.
. 2021-01-12 16:52:24.062 Got reply 1 to the command 16
. 2021-01-12 16:52:24.062 Getting current directory name.
> 2021-01-12 16:52:24.062 PWD
< 2021-01-12 16:52:24.257 257 "/ä" is current directory.
. 2021-01-12 16:52:24.257 Got reply 1 to the command 16
. 2021-01-12 16:52:24.257 Retrieving directory listing...
> 2021-01-12 16:52:24.257 TYPE A
< 2021-01-12 16:52:24.452 200 Type set to A.
> 2021-01-12 16:52:24.452 PASV
< 2021-01-12 16:52:24.647 227 Entering Passive Mode (127,0,0,1,239,2).
> 2021-01-12 16:52:24.647 LIST -a
. 2021-01-12 16:52:24.647 Connecting to 127.0.0.1:61186 ...
< 2021-01-12 16:52:24.842 150 Opening ASCII mode data connection.
< 2021-01-12 16:52:25.041 226 Transfer complete.
. 2021-01-12 16:52:25.046 Data connection closed
. 2021-01-12 16:52:25.046 01-12-21  10:47AM                    0 Nuevo documento de texto.txt
. 2021-01-12 16:52:25.047 Directory listing successful
. 2021-01-12 16:52:25.047 Got reply 1 to the command 2
. 2021-01-12 16:52:25.047 ..;D;0;1899-12-30T01:00:00.000Z;0;"" [0];"" [0];---------;0
. 2021-01-12 16:52:25.047 Nuevo documento de texto.txt;-;0;2021-01-12T15:47:00.000Z;1;"" [0];"" [0];---------;0
. 2021-01-12 16:52:25.117 Session upkeep
```

Comment: What does the question have to do with [tag:node.js]? Is this even a [programming question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl I am doing this in Nodejs, it has to do with knowledge concerning the FTP protocol, which afaik, is ontopic.

Comment: So if it is a programming question, post your code.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl will it help you understand the issue? Or the reader.

Comment: We need [mcve].

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Can you reproduce this?

Comment: Can you post WinSCP log file showing a successful listing of that folder?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl there you have one. I hope I didn't trim anything important.

Comment: Complete log please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I managed to understand what was going on, (thanks to a packet sniffing tool called wireshark), it was basically a typical case of an encoding problem. For the ftp clients, what was going on is basically ftp only receives latin-1 encoding, but node converts it to utf8 behind the scenes.
So for example my terminal was set to utf-8, so it kept sending utf-8 messages to the the latin-1 server, which of course it didn't know how to interpret.

But I discovered a command (in unix) that allows you to convert utf-8 to latin-1, and you use use it like this on the terminal
`>luit -encoding ISO-8859-1 ftp` this translates utf-8 to latin-1, and then it succeeded in listing the file.

Now for the case in node-js, the only thing I had to do was to stop node-js from converting the string to UTF-8, and to convert it to latin-1 instead. the Library however had hardcoded the utf-8 string, so, I had to options, modify the library or search for an alternative that supports such encoding.

Surprisingly, I had to do the later one, since I didn't have luck on finding another ftp library, I had the good fortune of finding [`@icetee/ftp`](http://github.com/icetee/node-ftp/issues/22), which is a fork of the original ftp package. Basically I had to make a fork and modify this [line](https://github.com/icetee/node-ftp/compare/master...kreijstal-contributions:master). And now everything works for my server, hopefully, there will be a setting on the future for this package. And that's how I solved it.